# Add version js and css files in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, css, versioning

I want to add **version** in **`js`** and **`css`** files in **Magento2**. I want browser to request url like

> http://example.com/pub/media/styles.css?ver=1.0.0

Instead of

> http://example.com/pub/media/styles.css

How can I achieve this ? In which file I need to make the changes.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the config option "Sign Static Files", as per [the documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/static-file-signature.html):

> To enable signed static files:
>
> 1. On the Admin sidebar, tap **Stores**. Then under **Settings**, choose **Configuration**.
> 2. In the panel on the left under **Advanced**, choose **Developer**.
> 3. Expand the **Static Files Settings** section.
> 4. Set **Sign Static Files** to “Yes.”
> 5. When complete, tap **Save Config**.

Comment: In firefox the css and js files is already stored in local cache. No matter what I do it never fetches the fresh content from server. If I use static sign files the url I get is http://example.com/pub/ver3423427/static/print.min.js . But when I open browser it always request http://example.com/pub/static/print.min.js . That's why I want to add version like print.min.js?ver=1.0.0 .

Comment: @linux404 I'm not sure what your problem is. Enabling this configuration will include a version tag, as in your example, in the URL (ver3423427). This means the browser will load a new version of that asset.

Comment: It is not working. In Firefox it always fetching from local cache. The js and css url path is not changing. I checked in developer console request url has not added version part.

Comment: Make sure you flush your Magento cache after changing the configuration, and run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. Also, make sure you have a rewrite in place for the verXXXX URLs, for example in the Magento supplied [sample nginx conf](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/nginx.conf.sample#L101-L104).

Answer (score 0):

- Go to menu Content > Design : Configuration
- Edit default Global scope > Edit
- Look at the bottom toggle "Other Settings" > HTML Head
- Add version in the end.

Run command in command prompt

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and clear cache it will work

Comment: How about files like print.min.css,styles-l.min.css  which are  inside  pub/static directory ?

Comment: check vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml  you can override this layout and change version